# Multiple ipn notifiy.. how to limit that?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

maybe there's something wrong on my paypal-ipn.php ?
I have a Ads Website, so users pay for Ads, but i receive multiple ipn notify so everytime the Ads goes on top of the page like was the newest..
Can you help me ?

```
    <?php

// this is the paypal ipn listener which waits for the request
function gc_ipn_listener() {

    // validate the paypal request by sending it back to paypal
    function gc_ipn_request_check() {

        define('SSL_P_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
        define('SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');

        $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if (!preg_match('/paypal\.com$/', $hostname)) {
            $ipn_status = 'Validation post isn\'t from PayPal';
            if (get_option('paypal_ipn') == true) {
                wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), $ipn_status, 'fail');
            }
            return false;
        }

        // parse the paypal URL
        $paypal_url = ($_REQUEST['test_ipn'] == 1) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_P_URL;
        $url_parsed = parse_url($paypal_url);


        $post_string = '';
        foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
            $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
        }
        $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
        // get the correct paypal url to post request to
        $get_paypal = get_option('pay_method_paypal');
        if (is_array($get_paypal)):
            $paypal_mode_status = $get_paypal['paypal_sandbox'];
        endif;
        if ($paypal_mode_status == true)
            $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
        else
            $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);


        $ipn_response = '';


        if (!$fp) {
            // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
            // will be in the log.
            $ipn_status = "fsockopen error no. $err_num: $err_str";
            if (get_option('paypal_ipn') == true) {
                wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), $ipn_status, 'fail');
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            // Post the data back to paypal
            fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
            fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
            fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

            // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
            }
            fclose($fp); // close connection
        }

        // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the $ipn_status and log for details.
        if (!preg_match("/VERIFIED/s", $ipn_response)) {
            $ipn_status = 'IPN Validation Failed';
            if (get_option('paypal_ipn') == true) {
                wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), $ipn_status, 'fail');
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            $ipn_status = "IPN VERIFIED";
            if (get_option('paypal_ipn') == true) {
                wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), $ipn_status, 'SUCCESS');
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    // if the test variable is set (sandbox mode), send a debug email with all values
    if (isset($_REQUEST['test_ipn'])) {
        $_REQUEST = stripslashes_deep($_REQUEST);
        if (get_option('paypal_ipn') == true) {
            wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), 'PayPal IPN Debug Email Test IPN', "" . print_r($_REQUEST, true));
        }
    }

    // make sure the request came from classicraft (pid) or paypal (txn_id refund, update)
    if (isset($_REQUEST['txn_id']) || isset($_REQUEST['invoice'])) {
        $_REQUEST = stripslashes_deep($_REQUEST);

        // if paypal sends a response code back let's handle it
        if (gc_ipn_request_check()) {

            // send debug email to see paypal ipn post vars
            if (get_option('paypal_ipn') == true) {
                wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), 'PayPal IPN Debug Email Main', "" . print_r($_REQUEST, true));
            }
            // process the ad since paypal gave us a valid response
            //do_action('gc_init_ipn_response', $_REQUEST);
            gc_handle_ipn_response($_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'gc_ipn_listener');

function gc_handle_ipn_response($request) {
    global $wpdb;

    //step functions required to process orders
    //include_once("wp-load.php");
    // make sure the ad unique trans id (stored in invoice var) is included
    if (!empty($request['txn_id'])) {


        // process the ad based on the paypal response
        switch (strtolower($request['payment_status'])) :

            // payment was made so we can approve the ad
            case 'completed' :
                update_option('cc_payment_status', 'yes');
                //Update listing
                cc_set_listing($request['post_id']);

                //Renewing listing
                gc_renew_listing($request['post_id'], $request['pkg_type']);

                //Upgrading listing
                $upgrade_meta_values = get_post_meta($request['post_id'], 'cc_add_type', true);
                if ($upgrade_meta_values == "free") {
                    cc_upgrade_listing($request['post_id'], $request['mc_gross']);
                }

                //Set transactions fields
                cc_set_transaction($request);
                //admin email confirmation
                //TODO - move into wordpress options panel and allow customization
                wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), 'Payment Receive', "A membership payment has been completed. Check to make sure this is a valid order by comparing this messages Paypal Transaction ID to the respective ID in the Paypal payment receipt email.");

                //Mail details to admin email
                $mailto = get_option('admin_email');
                $subject = __('PayPal IPN - payment receiver', THEME_SLUG);
                $headers = 'From: ' . __('Classicraft Admin', THEME_SLUG) . ' <' . get_option('admin_email') . '>' . "\r\n";
                $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

                $message = __('Dear Admin,', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('The following payment is receive on your %s website.', THEME_SLUG), $blogname) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payment Details', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('-----------------') . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer PayPal address: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['payer_email'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Transaction ID: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['txn_id'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer first name: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['first_name'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer last name: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['last_name'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payment type: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['payment_type'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Amount: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['mc_gross'] . " (" . $request['mc_currency'] . ")\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= __('Full Details', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('-----------------') . "\r\n";
                $message .= print_r($request, true) . "\r\n";
                //admin email
                wp_mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);

                $blogtime = current_time('mysql');
                $transaction_details .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r";
                $transaction_details .= "Payment Details for Listing ID #{$request['post_id']}\r";
                $transaction_details .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r";
                $transaction_details .= "Listing Title: {$request['post_title']} \r";
                $transaction_details .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r";
                $transaction_details .= "Trans ID: {$request['txn_id']}\r";
                $transaction_details .= "Status: {$request['payment_status']}\r";
                $transaction_details .= "Date: $blogtime\r";
                $transaction_details .= "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r";
                $transaction_details = __($transaction_details, THEME_SLUG);
                $subject = __("Listing Submitted and Payment Success Confirmation Email", THEME_SLUG);
                $site_name = get_option('blogname');
                $fromEmail = 'Admin';
                $filecontent = $transaction_details;
                global $wpdb;
                $placeinfosql = "SELECT ID, post_title, guid, post_author from $wpdb->posts where ID ={$request['post_id']}";
                $placeinfo = $wpdb->get_results($placeinfosql);
                foreach ($placeinfo as $placeinfoObj) {
                    $post_link = $placeinfoObj->guid;
                    $post_title = '<a href="' . $post_link . '">' . $placeinfoObj->post_title . '</a>';
                    $authorinfo = $placeinfoObj->post_author;
                    $userInfo = get_author_info($authorinfo);
                    $to_name = $userInfo->user_nicename;
                    $to_email = $userInfo->user_email;
                    $user_email = $userInfo->user_email;
                }
                $headers = 'From: ' . $to_admin . ' <' . $user_email . '>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $to_admin;
                wp_mail($user_email, $subject, $filecontent, $headers); //email to client

                break;

            case 'pending' :
                update_option('cc_payment_status', 'no');
                // send an email if payment is pending
                $mailto = get_option('admin_email');
                $subject = __('PayPal IPN - payment pending', THEME_SLUG);
                $headers = 'From: ' . __('Classicraft Admin', THEME_SLUG) . ' <' . get_option('admin_email') . '>' . "\r\n";
                $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

                $message = __('Dear Admin,', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('The following payment is pending on your %s website.', THEME_SLUG), $blogname) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payment Details', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('-----------------') . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer PayPal address: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['payer_email'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Transaction ID: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['txn_id'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer first name: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['first_name'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer last name: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['last_name'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payment type: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['payment_type'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Amount: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['mc_gross'] . " (" . $request['mc_currency'] . ")\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= __('Full Details', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('-----------------') . "\r\n";
                $message .= print_r($request, true) . "\r\n";

                wp_mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);

                break;

            // payment failed so don't approve the ad
            case 'denied' :
            case 'expired' :
            case 'failed' :
            case 'voided' :
                update_option('cc_payment_status', 'no');
                //Expire listing 
                cc_listing_expire($request['post_id']);
                // send an email if payment didn't work
                $mailto = get_option('admin_email');
                $subject = __('PayPal IPN - payment failed', THEME_SLUG);
                $headers = 'From: ' . __('Classicraft Admin', THEME_SLUG) . ' <' . get_option('admin_email') . '>' . "\r\n";
                $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

                $message = __('Dear Admin,', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('The following payment has failed on your %s website.', THEME_SLUG), $blogname) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payment Details', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('-----------------') . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer PayPal address: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['payer_email'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Transaction ID: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['txn_id'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer first name: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['first_name'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer last name: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['last_name'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payment type: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['payment_type'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Amount: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['mc_gross'] . " (" . $request['mc_currency'] . ")\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= __('Full Details', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('-----------------') . "\r\n";
                $message .= print_r($request, true) . "\r\n";

                wp_mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);

                break;

            case 'refunded' :
            case 'reversed' :
            case 'chargeback' :
                update_option('cc_payment_status', 'no');
                //Expire listing 
                cc_listing_expire($request['post_id']);
                // send an email if payment was refunded
                $mailto = get_option('admin_email');
                $subject = __('PayPal IPN - payment refunded/reversed', THEME_SLUG);
                $headers = 'From: ' . __('Classicraft Admin', THEME_SLUG) . ' <' . get_option('admin_email') . '>' . "\r\n";
                $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

                $message = __('Dear Admin,', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('The following payment has been marked as refunded on your %s website.', THEME_SLUG), $blogname) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payment Details', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('-----------------') . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer PayPal address: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['payer_email'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Transaction ID: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['txn_id'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer first name: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['first_name'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payer last name: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['last_name'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Payment type: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['payment_type'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Reason code: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['reason_code'] . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('Amount: ', THEME_SLUG) . $request['mc_gross'] . " (" . $request['mc_currency'] . ")\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= __('Full Details', THEME_SLUG) . "\r\n";
                $message .= __('-----------------') . "\r\n";
                $message .= print_r($request, true) . "\r\n";

                wp_mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);

                break;
        endswitch;
    }
}

add_action('gc_init_ipn_response', 'gc_handle_ipn_response');
?>
```

Comment: PayPal reattempts IPNs until you complete a verification round-trip. It's not clear from your question if you are completing this, or what circumstances you are seeing continued IPNs? (Also, if you do followup transactions, e.g. captures against authorizations or orders, these can generate new/distinct IPNs...)